# Как вписать блок в блок без усечения ширины и скрыть часть блока за пределами родительского блока?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть код :

```html
<head>
<style>
 .a{
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: inherit;
 }
 .b{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="a">
 <div class="b"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

нужно выступающую часть блока **Б** скрыть за пределами блока **А** без усечения его ширины, вот таким образом:

[image: пример]

что бы выступающей части видно не было.

Comment: спасибо @Doofy, то что нужно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.a { overflow: hidden; }` `.b { position: relative; }`

```css
.a {
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.b {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```